# Cannot pass results from models to index file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to get my node mysql setup working. In my model **event.js** I have the following code:

```
Event.getEvents = function(results) { 
  db.query("select * from com_event_details where type='featured'", function(error, results, fields ) { 
   return results; 
  }); 
};
```

And in my **index.js** I try to return the results from the getEvents.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
  Event.getEvents(function(results) { 
   res.send(results); 
  });
```

});

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Somehow I am not able to pass the results from the model to the index file.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a callback to `Event.getEvents`, but in that function you didn't use the callback.

Use this instead:

```
Event.getEvents = function(callback) {
  db.query("select * from com_event_details where type='featured'", callback); 
};


app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
  Event.getEvents(function(error, results) { 
    res.send(results); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises in node to return the results as shown below

```
function getResult() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            db.query("select * from com_event_details where type='featured'", function(error, results, fields) {
                resolve(results);
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            reject(ex);
        };
    });
}
```